# Iteration Function

Tags: python, function, loops, pi

I am trying to write a function that will calculate the value for pi. I want to return the new values of C and I (as well as π) from the function, and then use the new C and I as inputs for the next iteration.

Here is my code:

```
def pi_func(I_i,C_i):

    C = (2*C_i*I_i)/(C_i+I_i)
    I = sqrt(C*I_i)
    pi = (C+I)/2

    print C
    print I

    return pi

I_3 = ((sqrt(3)/2)/(.5))*1.5
C_3 = (.5/(sqrt(3)/3))*6

print pi_func(I_3,C_3)
```

Okay, below is my newest code.

```
def pi_func(I_i,C_i):

    new_C = (2*C_i*I_i)/(C_i+I_i)
    new_I = sqrt(new_C*I_i)
    pi = (new_C+new_I)/2

    print "C = ", new_C
    print "I = ", new_I

    return (pi,new_I,new_C)

I_3 = ((sqrt(3)/2)/(.5))*1.5
C_3 = (.5/(sqrt(3)/3))*6
print "I = %r" %I_3
print "C = %r" %C_3

for i in xrange(100):
    x = pi_func(I_3,C_3)
    print "PI = %r" %x[0]
    I_3 = x[1]
    C_3 = x[2]


print "Here is the machine accuracy for pi: %r" % np.pi
```

I want to get machine accuracy which is:

`Here is the machine accuracy for pi: 3.141592653589793`

But my program gives me: `PI = 3.141592653589792`

And since I am telling my program to do 100 iterations, it does stop until then. But the value for pi is calculated well before the 100th iteration.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean.  Do you mean you want to return the new values of C and I (as well as π) from the function, and then use the new C and I as inputs for the next iteration?

Comment: Yeah that is what I mean.

Comment: OK; please update the question to say so.  You can create tuples in Python; you can return tuples; you can get values out of tuples.  Can you not use tuples to solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do the job iteratively:

```
from math import sqrt

def pi_func(I_i,C_i):

    C = (2*C_i*I_i)/(C_i+I_i)
    I = sqrt(C*I_i)
    pi = (C+I)/2

    print "C  = ", C
    print "I  = ", I

    return (pi, I, C)

I_3 = ((sqrt(3)/2)/(.5))*1.5
C_3 = (.5/(sqrt(3)/3))*6
print "C3 = ", C_3
print "I3 = ", I_3

for i in xrange(10):
    x = pi_func(I_3,C_3)
    print "PI = ", x[0]
    I_3 = x[1]
    C_3 = x[2]
```

Sample output:

```
C3 =  5.19615242271
I3 =  2.59807621135
C  =  3.46410161514
I  =  3.0
PI =  3.23205080757
C  =  3.21539030917
I  =  3.10582854123
PI =  3.1606094252
C  =  3.1596599421
I  =  3.13262861328
PI =  3.14614427769
C  =  3.14608621513
I  =  3.13935020305
PI =  3.14271820909
C  =  3.14271459965
I  =  3.14103195089
PI =  3.14187327527
C  =  3.14187304998
I  =  3.14145247229
PI =  3.14166276113
C  =  3.14166274706
I  =  3.14155760791
PI =  3.14161017748
C  =  3.1416101766
I  =  3.14158389215
PI =  3.14159703438
C  =  3.14159703432
I  =  3.14159046323
PI =  3.14159374877
C  =  3.14159374877
I  =  3.141592106
PI =  3.14159292739
```

If you want to do it recursively, it is not very much harder — the main issue is when to stop recursing.

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in base case here. I think it's an approximation technique where pi is the calculus limit as (in my answer) `iterations` approaches infinity.

Comment: That's why I said the issue is when to stop recursing — under what circumstances are you going to consider the approximation done?  When the answer doesn't change in the Nth decimal digit (for some value of N, such as 10)?  Or some pre-determined number of iterations, as in the code I show?  Or some other technique?  There are many possibilities.  If you implement a recursive solution, you have to choose what is going to stop the recursion (because if you don't, the recursion won't stop).